# select two columns base on different condition in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    $inventory_in = $db->get_one("SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Qty), 0) 
                    FROM inventory Where id=12 AND inv_type = 'in' LIMIT 1");

    $inventory_out = $db->get_one("SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Qty), 0) 
                     FROM inventory Where id=12 AND inv_type = 'out' LIMIT 1");

    $inventory = $inventory_in - $inventory_out;
?>
```

Possible to combine *two queries into one*?

Thank you.

Comment: What's your motivation for wanting to combine them? Often times one complex query is slower than multiple simple ones.

Comment: @drewish my experience has been the exact opposite. In this example, doing an Aggregation twice (simple) is more expensive than doing two at the same time (complex). Its also really easy to get `SELECT N +1` problems with this idea that conceptual complexity is directly related to performance. In any case when its comes to perf its much better to find out what your budget is and measure to see if you've met that budget. Assumptions about what will be better in terms of perf is a bad idea

Comment: @ConradFrix Yeah I guess I was speaking more generally, in the aggregation case you're probably right that a single pass would be best, but like you say test it don't assume. Which is why I was trying to figure out what the motivation was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want both values output you can use SUM/CASE

```
SELECT
      COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN inv_type = 'in' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END ), 0) as  Sum1,
      COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN inv_type = 'out' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END ), 0) as  Sum2
FROM inventory 
WHERE id=12 
LIMIT 1
```

You may want to add `and inv_type  in ('in', 'out')` to your where clause but its not required.

Answer (score 0):

How about a conditional sum?

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN inv_type = 'in' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) InSum
    SUM(CASE WHEN inv_type = 'out' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OutSum
WHERE
    id = 12
```

Or if you just want the result

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE inv_type WHEN 'in' THEN 1 WHEN 'out' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) TotalSum
WHERE
    id = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT inv_type, COALESCE(SUM(Qty), 0) 
FROM inventory
WHERE id=12 AND inv_type IN ('in', 'out')
GROUP BY inv_type
```